# jquery ui accordion ajax troubles

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-9

I've got this accordion,  which i have sections of that load there content ajaxly on the first opening.  It works great in ff, ie 8, and pretty much every browser.  but in IE 9,  if i click the arrow/triangle it doesn't.

i rigged that up like so:

```
$("#accordian").accordion({
        collapsible: true,
        autoHeight: false,
        active : false,
        changestart: function (event, ui) {
            var clicked = $(this).find('.ui-state-focus').attr('id');
            if (clicked != "") {
                var alreadyLoaded = $('#' + clicked).attr('alreadyLoaded');
                if (alreadyLoaded == "false") {
                    var divToLoad = $('#' + clicked).attr('divToLoad');
                    var url = $('#' + clicked).attr('urlToLoadMe');

                    $('#' + divToLoad).load(url, function () {
                        //do some post load stuff
                    });
                    $('#' + clicked).attr('alreadyLoaded', "true");
                }
            }

        }

    });
```

my accordion looks something like this:

```
 <div id="accordian" style="height:400;">

            <h1 style="padding-left:25px;padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px;font-weight:bold;" id="ContactInformationHeader" urlToLoadMe="a url is here" alreadyLoaded="false" divToLoad="ContactInformationSearchSectionDiv">Contact Information</h1>
            <div id="ContactInformationSearchSectionDiv">
                loading
            </div>
    </div>
```

obviously with some more sections... but that's not important.

it works in firefox(3.X and 4), ie 8, but not 9.   if i click anywhere but the little triangle it works!

it seems like the wrong thing is getting the ui-state-active or something.  anyone had a similar problem?  ideas? help?

jquery version 1.4.1
jquery ui version 1.8.11

EDIT:
i've narrowed it down to this:   in ie 9, it seems to be that `changestart` is firing before `.ui-state-focus` is being assigned to everything, b/c it is null.  as is the `ui-state-active`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by changing changestart to change, so it fires later.   This means there is a slight delay in the ajax loading, but that is more acceptable then the arrow click not getting it at all!